# underscore.js how to combine 2 collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have two collections A and B. ( A,B have the exactly same structure, but different nodes values)

now I'd like to add A into B, with exactly the order: A B  and without merging or changing any 
nodes inside them. ( just like a joint action) { A } + {B}

I've read the documentation for underscore but couldn't find a proper function which gets this job done.

any idea?

==========update with example ========Sample is simplified from a larger structure, if there are errors please let me know=========

```
var collection1 = [{
"date": "29 January 2014",
"items": [{
    "name": "Jack",
    "score": 90,
    "title": "programmer"
}, {
    "name": "TOM",
    "score": 52,
    "title": "designer"
}]
}, {
"date": "28 January 2014",
"items": [{
    "name": "Jim",
    "score": 30,
    "title": "driver"
}, {
    "name": "William",
    "score": 52,
    "title": "worker"
  }]
}]



var collect2 = [{
"date": "26 January 2014",
"items": [{
    "name": "Marry",
    "score": 92,
    "title": "teacher"
}, {
    "name": "TOM",
    "score": 52,
    "title": "designer"
}]

}]
```

========expected output==============

```
[{
"date": "29 January 2014",
"items": [{
    "name": "Jack",
    "score": 90,
    "title": "programmer"
}, {
    "name": "TOM",
    "score": 52,
    "title": "designer"
}]
}, {
"date": "28 January 2014",
"items": [{
    "name": "Jim",
    "score": 30,
    "title": "driver"
}, {
    "name": "William",
    "score": 52,
    "title": "worker"
}]

}, {

"date": "26 January 2014",
"items": [{
    "name": "Marry",
    "score": 92,
    "title": "teacher"
}, {
    "name": "TOM",
    "score": 52,
    "title": "designer"
}]


}]
```

Comment: What if { aa: 'aa', bb: 'bb' } to be combined with { cc: 'cc', aa: 'bb' }? What is expected result?

Comment: Would be great if you add structure of collections A and B in the question.

Comment: they don't have duplicated nodes...

Comment: A simple sample of such a collection along with the expected output would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is simply [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
var foo = ['a','b','c'];
var bar = ['d','e','f'];

var all = foo.concat(bar); // ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Underscore#extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) as : `_.extend(collection1, collection2);`

**DEMO**

```
col1 = { aa: 'aa', cc: 'cc' }; col2 = { bb: 'bb', dd: 'dd' };
_.extend(col1, col2)
console.log(col1);
# Prints Object {aa: "aa", cc: "cc", bb: "bb", dd: "dd"}
```

Comment: sorry ram, they have same structure but with different values. So, _.extend will actually merge them two.

Comment: @Robert: In such case, it will be difficult to meet your requirement since 'key' inside collection suppose to be unique and wouldn't possible to exists elements with same key twice or more.